# How do I get a mutable reference out of a vector?

Tags: rust, reference, self, borrow-checker

Both the `run` and `send` methods need a `self` object, and the `send` function also needs a mutable `Packet` reference:

```rust
struct Package {
    id: u32,
}

impl Package {
    fn new(id: u32) -> Package {
        Package { id }
    }
}

struct Manager {
    packages: Vec<Package>,
}

impl Manager {
    fn new() -> Manager {
        Manager {
            packages: vec![
                Package::new(1),
                Package::new(2),
                Package::new(3),
                Package::new(4),
            ],
        }
    }
    fn run(&mut self) {
        for package in self.packages.iter_mut() {
            if package.id == 1 {
                self.send(package);
            }
            println!("{}", package.id);
        }
    }
    fn send(&self, package: &mut Package) {
        package.id = 23;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let manager = Manager::new();
    manager.run();
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:29:17
   |
27 |         for package in self.packages.iter_mut() {
   |                        ------------------------
   |                        |
   |                        mutable borrow occurs here
   |                        mutable borrow later used here
28 |             if package.id == 1 {
29 |                 self.send(package);
   |                 ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `manager` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:41:5
   |
40 |     let manager = Manager::new();
   |         ------- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut manager`
41 |     manager.run();
   |     ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

How I can refactor these two functions to get it working?

I don't want to copy the packet, since that would lead to lots of trouble with my original code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1: don't accept `&self` in `send()`. Just let it take the things from `self` that it needs, such as `&mut Package` and possibly other fields:

```
// call it with Self::send(package)
fn send(package: &mut Package) {
    package.id = 23;
}
```

Option 2: accept a package index instead of `&mut Package`:

```
fn run(&mut self) {
    for package_idx in 0..self.packages.len() {
        if self.packages[package_idx].id == 1 {
            self.send(package_idx);
        }
        println!("{}", self.packages[package_idx].id);
    }
}

fn send(&mut self, package_idx: usize) {
    self.packages[package_idx].id = 23;
}
```

Option 3: use interior mutability.

```
struct Manager {
    packages: Vec<RefCell<Package>>,
}

impl Manager {
    fn new() -> Manager { ... }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        for package in &self.packages {
            if package.borrow().id == 1 {
                self.send(package);
            }
            println!("{}", package.borrow().id);
        }
    }
    fn send(&self, package: &RefCell<Package>) {
        let package = package.borrow_mut();
        package.id = 23;
    }
}
```

Which option is right for you depends on your use case. All else being equal, I'd prefer option 1, then 2, then 3.

Comment: Even though I see your point that 1 is the best, my use case requires a self object. So I am going with 3.